# Issue with identifying object using its ID?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyVjH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMVXH.png)I am working on a Salesforce application and am trying to choose a value from a drop down for my test case but I keep getting a NoSuchElement exception.
I tried to identify the object using its ID

```
public void enterStep1Details()
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:hm:HiringId"));
    element.sendKeys("C");
}
```

Below is the HTML code

```
<select id="pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:BusinessSegment:selectedReqTypeId" name="pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:BusinessSegment:selectedReqTypeId" size="1" onchange="A4J.AJAX.Submit('pageid:theform',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:BusinessSegment:j_id57','oncomplete':function(request,event,data){RefreshText();},'parameters':{'pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:BusinessSegment:j_id57':'pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:BusinessSegment:j_id57'} } )" style="width:200px">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Clinical Informatics">Clinical Informatics</option>
   <option value="Corporate Services">Corporate Services</option>
   <option value="Early Development Services">Early Development Services</option>
   <option value="Executive Office">Executive Office</option>
   <option value="Late Phase Services">Late Phase Services</option>
   <option value="Product Registration">Product Registration</option>
   <option value="Strategic Solutions">Strategic Solutions</option>
   <option value="Therapeutic Expertise">Therapeutic Expertise</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: public void enterStep1Details() {
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:hm:HiringId"));
  element.sendKeys("C");
 }

Comment: Please edit the question and put the additional details in there, properly formatted. It will make it easier for everyone to see and more likely to get answered.

Comment: I updated the question. please let me know if it makes sense

Comment: You realize that the code you provided is NOT using the ID that you specified in the HTML?

Comment: Copied the wrong one ... below is the updated one ....                                public void enterStep1Details() { WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:BusinessSegment:selectedReqTypeId"‌​)); element.sendKeys("C"); }

Comment: Do you need the Entire page source ? It seems that there is a frame in the page. But i believe we can identify the object using ID , no matter the location of the object inside a frame.

Comment: If the element is in a frame you will need to use `switchTo()` to get into the frame to access the element. You should be able to find lots of reference material on SO for this and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much jeff, It worked as per your suggestion. Great Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, it's built from other parts so you will likely need to use the entire ID to be sure that it's unique on the page. You could experiment with AGill's answer but I would just go with the entire ID.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("pageid:theform:Block:NewHireRequisitionId:BusinessSegment:selectedReqTypeId"));
```

---

After talking to the OP some more, turns out the element is in an `IFRAME`. An example of how to handle this is below.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

after done in the frame, make sure you switch back to the default content.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

There are other options for accessing `IFRAME`s but this should get you started.

Comment: I have tried this intially by giving the entire ID, It wasnt working.

Comment: Then you need to provide a lot more info in your question.

Comment: You should provide whatever you think we will need to understand and answer the question. I would absolutely provide the relevant HTML in the question since it is most likely required to answer the question.

Comment: Hi Jeff, please suggest some other option for this?

Comment: Added some basic code for dealing with an IFRAME after the conversation we had.

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem, please accept an answer so the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: How do i do that? please advise

Comment: There should be a check? I think next to each answer. Honestly it's been a long time since I've asked a question and don't remember. Look around the top left of the answer and hover over stuff... something should be labelled accept or something like that ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a css selector for this. Look for the static portion of the `id` e.g. look for prefix or suffix or any substring which is unique and static and use that to write the css selector.

For example if `id` ends with text "selectedReqTypeId" you can write

```
By.cssSelector("[id$=selectedReqTypeId]")
```

Also you can write for `matching pattern` or `substring` like:

```
By.cssSelector("[id*='pattern']")
```

or as per your given code, you can probably write

```
By.cssSelector("[id*='NewHireRequisitionId']") //just an example
```

Similarly for `startsWith`, you can write:

```
By.cssSelector("[id^=startingText]")
```

Comment: I tried all the options and its still not working for me. I am still getiing NoSuchElementException

Comment: Hi Agill, Please suggest some other option for this
?

Comment: As you are getting `NoSuchElementException`, so the driver is not able to find the element. This solution was based on the information you provided in your question. As `id` is not working, you need to provide more info (more html may be). Sometimes to get a reliable locator, you need to look at parent html tags and if there is a frame or so.

Comment: i have added an image for the HTML code, please help to identify the object.

Comment: Click on the link (enter image description here) to view the image

Answer (score 0):

If the element is in a frame you will need to use switchTo() to get into the frame to access the element. You should be able to find lots of reference material on SO for this and elsewhere. – JeffC 21 hours ago